# re train yolo4 weight with the .weights extension

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I have trained `yolo` network weight with the ".weights" extension, and am trying to update it using `darknet`, and more dataset. Is there anyway I can use this weight and update it with more dataset than using original provided weight (.conv.74)? Or I need to train everything from the beginning?

Here is what I am trying to do, but it is not giving me anything.

./darknet detector train tmp_yolo/cfg/obj.data tmp_yolo/cfg/yolov3-tiny-custom.cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/Training_Forest3D/Weight/yolov3.weights

Answer (score 0):

The error of "not giving me anything" is too vague to be useful.

But what I'm guessing you've run into is you told Darknet to train for a certain number of batches.  Known as "max batches" in the .cfg file.  So when you attempt to train again and re-using the previous weights, Darknet is telling you it has already reached that value, and simply exits with a message.  The message it logs is [this one](https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet/blob/master/src-lib/detector.cpp#L477):

```
If you want to re-start training, then use the flag "-clear" in the training command.
```

So you have 3 options:

- Use the `-clear` command as it is telling you to do.
- Increase your max batches in your .cfg file to force Darknet to continue training.
- Retrain from scratch.

Note this is also addressed in the Darknet/YOLO FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#training_command

If the problem is something else, you'll need to edit your original question to make it clear exactly what sort of issue you ran into.